# Extracting a substring before one of two characters using regex

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

So I have an initial file set:

```
file1.txt 
file2.txt
```

When I make a change to these files and save them, I append a time stamp to them, so they'd become:

```
fileN_DD-Mon-YYYY_HHMMSS.txt
```

But if I was to make any additional saves, the timestamps would begin stacking:

```
fileN_DD-Mon-YYYY_HHMMSS_DD-Mon-YYYY_HHMMSS.txt
```

I need a way to get the substring that occurs before the first occurrence of either "." or "_" to get the string that is before them (i.e., actual file name ("fileN")).

I've gotten to this point with

```
int lastDot = fileName.getName().lastIndexOf('.'); 
String renamed = fileName.getName().substring(0,lastDot) + getDateTime() + fileName.getName().substring(lastDot);
```

I've tried using Scanner::useDelimiter to get the first occurrance of a "." or "_" using regexes but no luck.

```
String renamed = savedFileName(fileName)

public static String savedFileName(String fileName) {
        final String TXT = ".txt";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(fileName);
        s.useDelimiter(<regex>);
        String trueFileName = s.next();
        s.close();

        return trueFileName + getDateTime() + TXT;
```

for the regex, I've tried `"\\W"`, but that returns just the latest timestamp:

`_DD-Mon-YYYY_HHMMSS.txt`

, and `".|_"` but that returns this monstrosity:

```
fileN.txt_DD-Mon-YYYY.txt_(more timestamps).txt.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String`'s `split` method with regex pattern `\.|_`:

```
String longFile = "fileN_DD-Mon-YYYY_HHMMSS.txt";
String shortFile = "file1.txt ";
String pattern = "\\.|_"; // need to escape backslash
System.out.println(longFile.split(pattern)[0]);
System.out.println(shortFile.split(pattern)[0]);
```

Or, equivalently, regex `[._]`.

Output:

```
fileN
file1
```